# NGINX not resolving or ignoring variables

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I am using `set` in my nginx virtual hosts to set the domain once so I can just re-use it all over the file since I name my directories exactly like the domains.

The issue is that nginx seems to completly ignore the variables I set and it just uses the variable itself instead of the value. So `www.$appDomain` results in `www.$appDomain` instead of `www.domain.com`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Virtual Host `/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com`

```
server {
    set $appDomain "domain.com";

    root /var/www/html/$appDomain;

    server_name $appDomain www.$appDomain;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$appDomain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$appDomain/privkey.pem;
}
```

Error with `sudo nginx -t`

```
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/$appDomain/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/$appDomain/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/505015/12195